# Create json array from multiple sql table

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have create the json file from the sql table but the output is not same with the output i expected. Below is my code to create the json file from the sql table

```
<?php
include 'config.php';


$sql = "SELECT table_id, table_name,GROUP_CONCAT(price) price FROM tables INNER JOIN table_orders ON table_id = res_table_id GROUP BY table_id";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);

while($data1 = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $data[] = $data1;
}

$encoded_data = json_encode($data,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
file_put_contents('data_json',$encoded_data);

?>
```

The output will look like this

```
[
    {
        "table_id": "1",
        "table_name": "Table 1",
        "price": "20.00,15.00,7.90"
    },
    {
        "table_id": "2",
        "table_name": "Table 2",
        "price": "7.90,15.00"
    }
]
```

I want my result something like the output below:

```
{"table":[
    {
        "table_id": "1",
        "table_name": "Table 1",
        "price": [
            "20.00","15.00","7.90"
        ]
    },
    {
        "table_id": "2",
        "table_name": "Table 2",
        "price": [
            "7.90","15.00"
        ]
    }
]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

$sql = "SELECT table_id, table_name,GROUP_CONCAT(price) price FROM tables INNER JOIN table_orders ON table_id = res_table_id GROUP BY table_id";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
$data = [];

while($data1 = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $data1['price'] = explode(',', $data1['price']);
    $data[] = $data1;
}

$encoded_data = json_encode(['table' => $data], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
file_put_contents('data_json', $encoded_data);
```

What this does:

In your initial loop, you first format your array items in the way you want. Then you can format your JSON string in the nested structure you want by passing in the format you like.

There are a few ways to optimize this, but that's the gist of it.

Answer (score -1):

```
$my_new_data = [];
while($data1 = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    array_push($my_new_data, $data1);
}
```

Comment: Use array_push instead and file put contents should be the $my_new_data

Comment: The output is still same, the price can't change in array

Comment: [Please do not post an answer that consists essentially of
code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Please [edit] your
answer to include an explanation of how and why the code solves the problem,
when it should be used, what its limitations are, and if possible a link to
relevant documentation.